# WebView.postVisualStateCallback only works the first time

Tags: android, webview

I have an activity in an Android application that includes both native UI elements and a WebView. The WebView is normally hidden (`Visibility.GONE`), and it performs occasional work "in the background" on its JavaScript loop. On a particular button click, the WebView is made visible and the user can see the web page. On a subsequent button click, the WebView is hidden again. The user can repeat this process.

I added a call to [`WebView.postVisualStateCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#postVisualStateCallback(long,%20android.webkit.WebView.VisualStateCallback)) when the user presses the button to make the WebView visible. I only make the WebView visible during the [`VisualStateCallback.onComplete`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.VisualStateCallback#onComplete(long)). This works great *the first time* the user clicks the button and I make the WebView visible. However, after the user dismisses the WebView and I make it hidden again, I cannot repeat this process. Any subsequent call to `WebView.postVisualStateCallback` *never* results in another call to `VisualStateCallback.onComplete`.

```
mWebView.postVisualStateCallback(++mWebViewVisualStateCallback, new WebView.VisualStateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(long requestId) {
        if (requestId == mWebViewVisualStateCallback) {
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

I am *not* navigating to new web pages in the WebView. The web page is essentially a long-lived single-page app. The DOM may be changing in the WebView while it is in the background, which is why I'm trying to subsequently call `WebView.postVisualStateCallback`. I am testing on an emulator and Pixel 2 with Oreo 8.1/API 27.

Is it possible to use `WebView.postVisualStateCallback` multiple times on the same main frame? Why would `WebView.postVisualStateCallback` only work once?

Comment: in my case it isn't firing at all... there is also `WebViewCompat` class from AndroidX and same situation, not a single call... any ideas? did you resolved your issue? when you are setting your callback, maybe `onCreate` or `onPageStarted`?

Comment: @snachmsm Unfortunately, we found even more buggy behavior with `postVisualStateCallback` across different devices. We ended up abandoning the call altogether. :-(  We were adding this to a reusable, utility library. We didn't want to force the support library dependency, so we didn't test with WebViewCompat, just the native WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [android website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#postVisualStateCallback(long,%20android.webkit.WebView.VisualStateCallback)), I think you might need to consider these situations when using `postVisualStateCallback()`

> To guarantee that the WebView will successfully render the first frame
> after the VisualStateCallback#onComplete method has been called a set
> of conditions must be met:
>
> 1. If the WebView's visibility is set to VISIBLE then the WebView must be attached to the view hierarchy.
> 2. If the WebView's visibility is set to INVISIBLE then the WebView must be attached to the view hierarchy and must be made VISIBLE from
>    the VisualStateCallback#onComplete method.
> 3. If the WebView's visibility is set to GONE then the WebView must be attached to the view hierarchy and its LayoutParams's width and height
>    need to be set to fixed values and must be made VISIBLE from the
>    VisualStateCallback#onComplete method.

Hope this is helpful~